# Get the file name of a Qt label image

Tags: c++, image, qt

I am using Qt creator for a c++ gui. I am making a blackjack game. I wanted to be able to change a label to the backside of the card (call it "backside.png"), to the frontside of the card (call it "frontside.png").

When the person clicks on one of the standard buttons, I want to check if the image on the label(call it "cardlabel") is displaying the backside of the card, or the frontside of the card.

If it is showing the backside, then I will change the label to show the frontside of the card, and vice versa.

Is there anyway someone is able to show me (through code), how I can ask "cardlabel", for what image name it is currently using and check to see which side it is currently on. This would be a tremendous help for my project. Thanks!!

Comment: You can set any `QPixmap` on the `QLabel`. The API is flexible, it does not require that this `QPixmap` comes from a file. You could be getting that `QPixmap` from any IO device (the network for example), or it can be hardcoded in the code. In short, **there is no way to get back to the filename once you have the `QPixmap` object loaded.** So, once you say `QPixmap("file.png");`, the image data is read from the file and loaded into the `QPixmap`, even the fact that the data comes from a file is no longer available from the `QPixmap`.

Comment: I think that you need to save this state information in another variable, maybe have a separate `QString` to save the name of the file currently being loaded in the `QPixmap`. . .

Comment: Why not inherit from QLabel, e.g. creating your own Card class, and store information there whether it's showing the front or back side of a card. You know, OOP style.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old but I can suggest you to "carry" within each object a variable that contains the value of the pixmap so you can read/change it before affecting it to the setPixmap.

My code is in Python but you can translate :)

```
self.ui.qlabel.img = "img/light_red.png"
if someRandomCondition:
      self.ui.qlabel.lum = "img/light_green.png"
else:
      self.ui.qlabel.lum = "img/light_red.png"
self.ui.qlabel.setPixmap(QPixmap(self.ui.qlabel.lum))
print(self.ui.qlabel.lum)
```